# is 'And' change the single to plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

My confused rule is : **The verb in an or, either/or, or neither/nor sentence agrees with the noun or pronoun closest to it.**

How it is possible that this sentence is correct !

*She, my friends, and I are not going to the festival.*

Reference : [Rule 3](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

Comment: Conjoined subjects are plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. The common rule is - unless "**and**" makes multiple subjects a single entity you should use the plural form:

- *A pen* and *a book* **are** on the table. (*Two subject "a pen" and "a book" don't make a single entity so the plural verb is used.*)
- *Bread and butter* **is** good for breakfast. (*Two subject "bread" and "butter" make a single entity so the singular verb is used.*)

---

- *She*, *my friends*, and *I* **are** not going to the festival. (*Multiple subjects that don't make a single entity so the plural verb is used.*)

Rule #3 in your reference doesn't apply to "**and**"; it only applies to "**or/either-or/neither-nor**".

> The verb in an **or**, **either/or**, or **neither/nor** sentence agrees with the noun or pronoun closest to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple enumeration. Enumeration is mentioning (a number of things) one by one. It's collective, thus plural.